# Does Zookeeper clients keep open lots of TCP connections & if so, how scalable is it ? Any limits?

Tags: scalability, apache-zookeeper

We are designing a distribution configuration substrate for our object store with zookeeper. Once we have migrated all the configurations to zk, there will be hundreds of apps that will register for events with zk. Does this result in lots of open tcp connections ? Any scalability issues ? What are the best practices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a lot of TCP connections, but as mentioned by jterrace, 100's is a small number and this email thread indicates zookeeper begins to show issues at about 20K clients connecting to a 3 node ensemble(obviously depends on the capacity of your servers): http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/zookeeper-dev/201105.mbox/%3CE7FE30AF6EB51F4FBB74E39CA896472F94D604@SC-MBX01-5.TheFacebook.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

If you only have hundreds of applications, zookeeper will handle that traffic with no problem. It's designed to handle potentially thousands of simultaneous clients per zookeeper server. See this paper for more technical details: http://www.usenix.org/event/atc10/tech/full_papers/Hunt.pdf